# Change fieldType string to float in Influx on command: show field keys

Tags: influxdb

I would like to change prm.fieldType from string to float, it is possible?

Here is what I have right now:

```
> show field keys
name: dev
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
guid     string

name: prod
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
prm      string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the measurement and reinsert data with correct type (as a float in your case).

Comment: Yep, this is what I did, but this  is not cool! What if I cant regenerate my data ?

Comment: See https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-change-a-field-s-data-type

Comment: New link: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.6/reference/faq/#can-i-change-a-fields-data-type "Flux type-conversion functions let you change a fields data type at query time. However, you cannot change the type of a field on disk."